# Enforce items at beginning and end of list

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can I modify this list so that all `p's` appear at the beginning, the `q's` at the end, and the values in between are sorted alphabetically?

```
l = ['f','g','p','a','p','c','b','q','z','n','d','t','q']
```

So I would like to have:

```
['p','p','a','b','c','d','f','g','n','t','z','q','q']
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with the following `key`:

```
sorted(l, key = lambda s: (s!='p', s=='q', s))
['p', 'p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'n', 't', 'z', 'q', 'q']
```

---

**Explanation**

To get a better idea of how this is working, the following list comprehension aims to replicate what is being returned from the `lambda` function defined in the `key` argument prior to making comparisons:

```
t = [(s!='p', s=='q', s) for s in pl]

print(t)
[(True, False, 'f'),
 (True, False, 'g'),
 (False, False, 'p'),
 (True, False, 'a'),
 (False, False, 'p'),
 (True, False, 'c'),
 (True, False, 'b'),
 (True, True, 'q'),
 (True, False, 'z'),
 (True, False, 'n'),
 (True, False, 'd'),
 (True, False, 't'),
 (True, True, 'q')]
```

This will then be the `key` to be used to sort the items in the list, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

> The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes.

So taking into account that `False = 0` and `True = 1`, when this list of tuples is sorted the result will be the following:

```
sorted(t)
[(False, False, 'p'),
 (False, False, 'p'),
 (True, False, 'a'),
 (True, False, 'b'),
 (True, False, 'c'),
 (True, False, 'd'),
 (True, False, 'f'),
 (True, False, 'g'),
 (True, False, 'n'),
 (True, False, 't'),
 (True, False, 'z'),
 (True, True, 'q'),
 (True, True, 'q')]
```

Comment: Now, this is pretty cool.  Can you explain a bit?   sorted sorts True < characters 
< False?

Comment: @ScottBoston no, it returns a (bool, bool, str) tuple

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Ah.... Okay.  I think I see.  I'm going to have to play around with this a bit to get this cemented in my head.  Thanks.

Comment: So (False, False) comes first and (True,True) in the end. In between there will be (True,False)

Comment: For those of you who need this `sorted([(s!='p', s=='q', s) for s in l])` is a great visual of what is going on.

Answer (score 21):

One idea is to use a priority dictionary with a custom function. This is naturally extendable should you wish to include additional criteria.

```
L = ['f','g','p','a','p','c','b','q','z','n','d','t','q']

def sort_func(x):
    priority = {'p': 0, 'q': 2}
    return priority.get(x, 1), x

res = sorted(L, key=sort_func)

print(res)

['p', 'p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'n', 't', 'z', 'q', 'q']
```

Answer (score 15):

Use the `key` parameter in [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
l = ['f','g','p','a','p','c','b','q','z','n','d','t','q']

def key(c):
    if c == 'q':
        return (2, c)
    elif c == 'p':
        return (0, c)
    return (1, c)


result = sorted(l, key=key)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['p', 'p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'n', 't', 'z', 'q', 'q']
```

Answer (score 8):

Just define an appropriate key function:

```
>>> def _key(x):
...     if x == 'p':
...         return -1
...     elif x == 'q':
...         return float('inf')
...     else:
...         return ord(x)
...
>>> l = ['f','g','p','a','p','c','b','q','z','n','d','t','q']
>>> sorted(l, key=_key)
['p', 'p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'n', 't', 'z', 'q', 'q']
```

Note, every character is mapped to an integer >= 0, so we can just rely on `ord`, and since `-1` will always be less than anything returned by `ord`, we can use that for p, and for q, we can use infinity, so it will be alway greater than something returned by `ord`.

Answer (score 4):

You can find all `p` and `q` elements, filter the original list, and then sort:

```
l = ['f','g','p','a','p','c','b','q','z','n','d','t','q']
_ps, _qs = [i for i in l if i == 'p'], [i for i in l if i == 'q']
new_l = _ps+sorted(filter(lambda x:x not in {'q', 'p'}, l))+_qs
```

Output:

```
['p', 'p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'n', 't', 'z', 'q', 'q']
```

Comment: *If* you're going to do it this way, you can also just count the `p`s and `q`s: `['p']*l.count('p') + sorted(filter({'q', 'p'}.isdisjoint, l)) + ['q']*l.count('q')` which is the same time complexity. **Edit**: You can get rid of the `lambda` too.

Answer (score 2):

You could also store you front, middle and ends in a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then just add all three lists at the end:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ["f", "g", "p", "a", "p", "c", "b", "q", "z", "n", "d", "t", "q"]

keys = {"p": "front", "q": "end"}

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in l:
    d[keys.get(item, "middle")].append(item)

print(d["front"] + sorted(d["middle"]) + d["end"])
# ['p', 'p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'n', 't', 'z', 'q', 'q']
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this question is:

1. First find all p and q elements in list.
2. Filter the original list.
3. Then, finally sort the list.

---

```
list = ['f','g','p','a','p','c','b','q','z','n','d','t','q'];
noOfPs = [i for i in l if i == 'p']; 
noOfQs = [i for i in l if i == 'q'];
resultList= noOfPs + sorted(filter(lambda x:x not in {'q', 'p'}, l))+ noOfQs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `lambda` function as the key in `sorted()`:

```
l1 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: ((x == 'q') - (x == 'p'), x))

print(l1)
# ['p', 'p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'n', 't', 'z', 'q', 'q']
```

The function generates the following comparison keys:

```
func = lambda x: ((x == 'q') - (x == 'p'), x)

for i in l1:
    print(func(i))
```

Output:

```
(-1, 'p')
(-1, 'p')
(0, 'a')
(0, 'b')
...
(0, 't')
(0, 'z')
(1, 'q')
(1, 'q')
```